# How to 9-patch so icon always stick with centered text

Tags: android, button, drawable, nine-patch

[image: non-9 Patch image]

Basically, I wanted to have a button where text and icon stay in the middle of the button at all times. The Button has match_parent width and center gravity. I tried to use drawableLeft but that put icon on the left most of the Button and not next to the text.

So I'm trying to create 9-patch image as shown in the image above. Basically, I want all the text to stay in blue box with the cyan rounded rectangle (icon) next to it. The stretchable area is in red. However I just can't make it as the content area always overlap the icon.

Is this possible with 9-patch? Or should I wrap Layout around the TextView and use that as a button instead?

By the way, the included image is just to show what I plan to do. The actual image will be in other colors and without all the red.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a nine-patch image, you put some black lines on the right and bottom of the image. These lines define the region that will be use to place the content inside of your image.

Here is an example :

[image]

It will look like this :
 [image]

Comment: Yes, this will put the icon on the left of the view. However, I want the stretching to be done on the left-side of the view as well so that both the icon and content stay nicely in the middle of the screen. As stated in my question, this will work if I wrap a layout around it and make it center but that means I have to waste one layout for a trivial thing which isn't really ideal for me. Let me know if I mistook what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: You would rather make Android create a new image with the size of the screen than center a small image ? One solution is faster than the other.